# iPhone Detect Volume key press when application is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am developing an iphone app, and I want detect some action when the app is being running in background mode. Is possible detect the volumen button when is pressed to trigger some action in the app?.

My app try execute some panic alarm to alert the server that the user is in a dangerous situation.

Some ideas to cover this requirement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, you can't detect anything while your app is not currently running.

Comment: Read more about application states here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Your app will run in the background for a limited time unless its a music/location/voip app

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, in the official documentation of apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Its says it is only possible if the application requests extra time to the iOS

I'm sorry :(